# C++ assignment between different object types

Tags: c++, class, variable-assignment

I have a bunch of union classes (union_a, union_b, ...), all with same data members and 
different member functions.
I want to be able to assign an object of any class to object of any other class, and 
use it in any ctor for init.
A "work" union union_z is used as a mediator.
Everything works fine in VC. 
In GC the last line gets "error: conversion from ‘union_a’ to non-scalar type ‘union_b’ requested".

Help me if you can, I'm...

```
union union_z{int m;};

union union_a{
    int  m;

    union_a(){}
    union_a(union_z x){m = x.m;}

    void operator=(union_z x){m = x.m;}
    operator union_z(){return *(union_z *)this;}
};

union union_b{
    int  m;

    union_b(){}
    union_b(union_z x){m = x.m;}

    void operator=(union_z x){m = x.m;}
    operator union_z(){return *(union_z *)this;}
};

union_a  a;
union_b  b(a);
b = a;
union_b  b1 = a; //error: conversion from ‘union_a’ to non-scalar type ‘union_b’ requested
```

Answer (score 4):

G++ is correct.  The formal syntax of copy initialization is to
convert the expression to the right of the `=` to the target
type, then copy it.  Which in this case supposes an implicit
conversion from `union_a` to `union_b`.  And there isn't one;
the only conversion would require two user defined conversions,
and two user defined conversions can never be used in an
inplicit conversion.

See §8.5/16 and §13.3.1.4 (C++11, but the rules concering this
haven't changed with regards to earlier versions).

Comment: Two *implicit* user defined conversions, right? `union_b  b1 = static_cast<union_z>(a);` works.

Comment: You might add the relevant paragraph: [dcl.init]/17-6-1

Comment: @jrok Yes.  No explicit conversions can be part of an implicit conversion.

Comment: @jrok And in `union_b b1 = static_cast<union_z>( a );`, the type of the expression on the right is `union_z` (_because_ of the explicit cast).  So there is only one user defined conversion involved in converting it to `union_b`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, I know. I thought you'd mention that as a workaround for OP :)

Comment: @jrok I don't think he needs a work-around.  `union_b b1( a );` works just fine.

Comment: @JamesKanze
Thanks. Seems there's no simple solution. About 20 * 20 conversion functions is no simple for me, static_cast<union_z>(a) is no simple for the user compared with b(a).